# Splitting a string in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with several lines. For example

```
A               B       C    
awer.ttp.net    Code    554
abcd.ttp.net    Code    747
asdf.ttp.net    Part    554
xyz.ttp.net     Part    747
```

I want to make a SparkSQL statement to split just column a of the table and I want a new row added to the table D, with values awe, abcd, asdf, and xyz.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `split` function and get the first element for new Column `D`

Here is an simple example

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("awer.ttp.net","Code", 554),
  ("abcd.ttp.net","Code", 747),
  ("asdf.ttp.net","Part", 554),
  ("xyz.ttp.net","Part", 747)
)).toDF("A","B","C")

data.withColumn("D", split($"A", "\\.")(0)).show(false)

 //using SQL 

data.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")
data.sqlContext.sql("SELECT A, B, C, SUBSTRING_INDEX(A, '.', 1) as D  from tempTable")
```

Output:

```
+------------+----+---+----+
|A           |B   |C  |D   |
+------------+----+---+----+
|awer.ttp.net|Code|554|awer|
|abcd.ttp.net|Code|747|abcd|
|asdf.ttp.net|Part|554|asdf|
|xyz.ttp.net |Part|747|xyz |
+------------+----+---+----+
```

Comment: I am looking for a SQL statement as this is for a much larger file. The file is already loaded into spark. So I can't set data to be equal to something. So we have a reference to the spark table called data and it points to temptable in spark. So I just want the SQL command. I tried "SELECT A, B, C, SUBSTRING_INDEX(A, '.', 1) as D  from tempTable" but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can do something similar to the below in SparkSQL

```
select A,B,C, split(A,'\\.')[0] as D from tablename;
```